# Full Display of LInear mixed effects figure in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, mixed-models

I am facing a problem in R with illustrating my results. For some reason, my graphs are cut off. See figure attached. I tried playing around with settings, but nothing helped so far. Any ideas how I can change the margins, so the figures are not cut off? Many thanks in advance!

[image: Here is my plot]

```
# visual inspection of data 
fit<-model_full
# Plot model
plot <- plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("Condition", "Group"))+  #geom_line(size = 1) 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, NA), clip = "off") + theme_tq() +scale_colour_tq() + scale_fill_tq(light) + 
  labs(
    title = "",
    y = "Score [ 0-5 ]",
    x = "Condition") +  xlim(c("baseline", "60 bpm", "16 bpm", "10 bpm", "6 bpm", "random")) +
  ylim(c(0,5)  
  )+ ggplot2::labs(colour = "Group") + scale_color_manual(values=c('Red','Black'))
plot<- plot + theme_apa()  
plot
```

Comment: Remove your `ylim()` call.  If you *must* restruct the y-axis, use `coord_cartesian()`.  `ylim` filters the data then creates the graph.  `coord_cartesian()` draws the graph them "zooms" to the requested area.  As you have discovered, using `ylim()` can have unexpected side effects when interpolation or modelling is involved.

Comment: 100% @Limey! It works. Great. Thanks a million!